# Symlink all files in a folder to another folder on windows?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link

I have a project stored at `/website`. There is a hidden folder inside of it called .modman which contains a folder named `test`

content of `/website/.modman/test`:

```
foo/index.html
bar/test/index.html
```

Is there a way to symlink the content of `/website/.modman/test/` to `/website/` so that the new structure will look like this:

```
/website/foo/index.html
/website/bar/test/index.html
```

? I tried it with [modman-php](https://github.com/sitewards/modman-php), but it fails to create a symlink.

Comment: Just use the standard `mklink /d` command (NB you'll need to use back-slashes as directory path separators).

Comment: How would the exact command look like in my above example?

Comment: Off the top of my head, `mklink /d \website\foo \website\test\foo` and similar for `bar`. Type `mklink /?` for more information.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a lot of work on big projects though. Is there a simpler way, maybe a function?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve: if you are trying to make it appear that your test site is live, simply set up `/website` as the appropriate alias in your web server. This may be an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).